# Transferring an MWCellArray from C# to Matlab

Tags: c#, matlab, com, matlab-deployment

Lets just say, for arguments sake, I have MWCellarray temp:

```
MWCellArray temp = new MWCellArray(10000,11);
```

And I now wish to call a Matlab function to run some simple calculations upon it:

```
            MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();
            <THIS IS THE MISSING STEP>
            matlab.Execute("open 'C:\Program Filez\mymatlabcode.m'");
            matlab.Execute("[thisismyoutput] = mymatlabcode(temp)");
```

I now need to make sure I can pass temp into the matlab workspace first.  Obviously my first thought was:

```
 matlab.PutWorkspaceData("putworkspace", "base", temp);
```

But no: {"Not implemented (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004001 (E_NOTIMPL))"}

Seemingly I am going to have to turn the MWCellArray into a string array to use that command....

```
        //{
        //    int[] kDimensions = temp.Dimensions;
        //    string[,] stemp = new string[kDimensions[0], kDimensions[1]];

        //    for (int i = 0; i < kDimensions[0]; i++)
        //    {
        //        for (int j = 0; j < kDimensions[1]; j++)
        //        {
        //            stemp [i, j] = (temp[i + 1, j + 1]).ToString();
        //        }
        //    }
        //}
```

This is very slow.  And the real implementation is around 15 of the MWCellArrays and this conversion is taking 15-20 minutes.

So.  How can I do this in a sensible fashion?  I cannot see any other methods to enable the transfer.  Neither matlab.PutCharArray nor matlab.PutFullMatrix seem to be applicable.

Is there a way to speed up the loop considerably?  I am entirely new to c#

Alternatively I would have thought I ought to be able to save an MWCellArray as a .mat file on C drive and then load it? (loading is easy, saving has me stumped)

I would be interested in any insights you can offer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be confusing two types of interaction between MATLAB and .NET.

1. You can start a live copy of MATLAB as a COM Automation Server using `MLApp.MLApp`. The resulting object then has methods such as `PutCharArray`, `PutWorkspaceData` etc, which would take regular .NET `System.Array` variables as input; `Execute` to run a MATLAB command; and `GetFullMatrix` etc which return regular .NET `System.Array` variables as output.
2. Using the add-on product [MATLAB Builder for .NET](http://www.mathworks.com/products/netbuilder/), you can deploy MATLAB code to a .NET assembly. You can then call that assembly from .NET, and the functions you deployed are available as methods. These methods take things like `MWCellArray`, `MWNumericArray` etc as inputs, and return them as outputs.

You can't mix those two by, for example, passing a `MWCellArray` to `matlab.PutWorkspaceData`.

If your aim is to call a live copy of MATLAB, don't create `MWCellArray` variables - just pass over strings and arrays with `PutCharArray` and `PutFullMatrix`, execute stuff, then get the results back with `GetCharArray` and `GetFullMatrix`. [Here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f135590.html#f135616)'s an example from the MATLAB doc.

If your aim is to call a deployed .NET assembly, then instantiate that and call it (passing `MWCellArray` etc) rather than `MLApp.MLApp`. [Here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/dotnetbuilder/ug/bs3zxbx.html#bqh32vx-1)'s an example from the Builder for .NET doc.

Comment: You are correct to an extent.  The reason I have MWCellArrays is because they are what are passed to the DLL of Matlab, they are populated from SQL queries on a database earlier in the program.

This, then, is the 'Debug' option where I am able to execute through using the uncompiled matlab code on my computer - and step through using 'live' data.  Something without which I would be lost.

The slowness is a personal frustration as I am the only person who really encounters it.  Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

Save it as an ascii file, and load it likewise into matlab?
the format of the ascii file seems pretty simple: [load documentation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/load.html). The problem now is how to save as ascii from C#, which seems a bit simpler than the original problem to me :)

The only real format requirement is an equal number of elements on each row. You're limited to 2d matrices this way of course :(